# JavaScript Frames Manipulation

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of javascript with Phonegap application which works nice on iPhone but on Android it doesn't work.

```
var js = "var c = frames.content;";

js += "if (c.document.readyState == 'complete') {";

js += "var l = c.document.getElementsByName('login')[1];";

js += "var u = c.document.getElementById('user_id');";
js += "var p = c.document.getElementById('password');";

js += "if (u && p) {";

js += "u.value = '" + getData("username") + "';";
js += "p.value = '" + getData("password") + "';";

js += "l.click();";

js += "}";

js += "}";
```

The Android browser says there is **frames** object which is of type DOMWindow but there is no child frame named **content**. What I am doing wrong?

**UPDATED**
I solved it. I wasn't executing the JavaScript in the right WebView.

Comment: even frames.length is 0 whereas there are 2 frames in frameset.

Comment: it was my mistake. sorry about that.